# Get h3 tag text with identified element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image: page source]

I need to get the immediate previous h3 tag text whenever I find the class name "fa-spin". I have identified the element of "fa-spin" but not able identify the h3 tag text. I have tried the below code.

```
spin = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fa-spin')
spin.find_element_by_xpath('//.ancestor::h3') # throws InvalidSelectorException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `preceding`

```
spin = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fa-spin')
spin.find_element_by_xpath('.//preceding::h3[1]')
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Just had to add `.text` to get the text of h3 tag. Thanks.